# How to count rows in database table?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to make a variable

```
{{ $countEvents }}
```

which can count the number of rows from table Events...Now I have 18 rows( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUJoY.jpg ), I want to use this variable to my view. How can I be able to count the number of rows?

I've tried this

```
$events = Event::count();
```

but I got all data with all columns from my database, not the number of it!

Comment: Try finding all Events and then `count()` on the results then pass to the view

Comment: Could you post your **Event** model code? **Event::count()** should work without any problems and return only the count of rows, when **Event::all()->count()** will first receive all the rows from the table and then count the results (not the best way of doing it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
$countEvents = Event::count();

return view('view-name-here', compact('countEvents'));
```

this will allow you to use `{{ $countEvents }}` in your view

Comment: check this solution my man - nice and simple - you were on the right lines

Comment: you don't need to do `$events::all()` you can just do this above

Comment: no worries man glad you got there! - if you could please accept my answer that would be great

Comment: the countEvents worked for EventController. But can I add a countNews in EventController? I used $countNews = News::count(); but I've got undefined variable $countNews. the return is this return view('event.view_all_event',$data, compact('countEvents'), compact('countNews'));

Comment: yeah you can do that like this - Controller: `$countNews = \App\News::count();` and then `return view('view-name-here', compact('countEvents', 'countNews'));` - let me know how you get on

Comment: I used this method: return view('event.view_all_event',$data)
            ->with(compact('countEvents'))
            ->with(compact('countNews')); . It worked for me.Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DB query builder facade.

```
$data['countEvents'] = DB::table('events')->count();
```

Now in blade you can check integer value of `$countEvents`

Answer (score 1):

`count` is a Collection method. The query builder returns an array. So in order to get the count, you would just count it like you normally would with an array:

```
$eventCount = count($events);
```

If you have a Event model, then you can use Eloquent to get a Collection and then use the Collection's count method. Example:

```
$eventlist = Event::all();
$eventCount = $eventlist->count();
```